# GAE Python OAuth 2.0 NotAllowedError

Tags: python, python-2.7, google-app-engine, oauth-2.0

I have been trying hard to get the following python code example working, with no success 
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/oauth/

gae-test.py

```
from google.appengine.api import oauth
import logging
import traceback
import webapp2

class Test(webapp2.RequestHandler):
  def get(self):
    scope = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email'
    self.response.write('\noauth.get_current_user(%s)' % repr(scope))
    try:
      user = oauth.get_current_user(scope)
      self.response.write(' = %s\n' % user)
      self.response.write('- auth_domain = %s\n' % user.auth_domain())
      self.response.write('- email       = %s\n' % user.email())
      self.response.write('- nickname    = %s\n' % user.nickname())
      self.response.write('- user_id     = %s\n' % user.user_id())
    except oauth.OAuthRequestError, e:
      self.response.set_status(401)
      self.response.write(' -> %s %s\n' % (e.__class__.__name__, e.message))
      logging.warn(traceback.format_exc())

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', Test),
], debug=True)
```

and the app.yaml

```
application: mytestapp
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: .*
  script: gae-test.app
```

Everytime the error is **NotAllowedError**. It never takes the user to consent screen.

I have the client id created in GAE project (even though I don't think it is necessary for just retrieving user email), and also user consent form filled. I think all necessary APIs must be enabled since users.get_current_user() is working fine.

My requirement is to get rid of ugly user consent screen from users.get_current_user(), and hence been trying this approach.

Comment: Are you running this locally on dev_appserver, or, deployed to a production app on yourappname.appspot.com?

Comment: I am running live on appspot.com. Just updated my full code.

Answer (score 0):

`oauth.get_current_user` (with or without a scope argument) checks if the request to your app includes an authorization header minted (A) for your app and (B) including the requested scope if any.

To prepare the token, the *program* that's sending your app the request must have followed the steps outlined at https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2 . I emphasize *program* because a request coming straight from a browser will not have an appropriate authorization header -- unless the browser is running a Javascript program (presumably also previously supplied by your app) that knows how to go through the hoops in question.

I don't know how this would ever let you "get rid of ugly user consent screen" -- which is not displayed by users.get_current_user itself, but rather from the Google authentication and authorization servers (where, inevitably, any program needing to mint an OAuth2 token will end up).

How else, but on the consent screen, would a user ever agree to give your app whatever scope you're requesting, including, for example, knowing about the user's email?

Comment: Thanks Alex. How do I send authorization header from my application?

Comment: @Nick, users.get_current_user is the standard GAE way to get authorization -- if that's not good for you, see the OAuth2 URL I already gave (you'll have to develop and serve to the browser some Javascript to follow those steps -- sorry, but Javascript is not my superpower:-).

Comment: Oh thanks :) I will sticket to users.get_current_user and let my website FB count give visitors confidence that ugly google sso screen is not a hacking website :)

Comment: @Nick, sounds good (so maybe you can accept this answer by clicking on the checkmark-shaped outline on its left) -- also, if you have specific suggestions about how the looks of Google's consent screen could be improved when it's reached from a `users.get_current_user` call, please post them as a detailed feature request at https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/list -- we monitor that issue tracker and will ensure the feature request reaches the proper decision maker (here, I guess, the UI experts) for them to accept or reject -- thanks in advance!